# Not able to download and install Django using Pip on windows 7

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install django using pip but I am not able to do it. Is there any other way to install Django.

I tried like below.

```
pip install Django
```

But I got the below error.

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken 
by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000041C8198>, 'Connection to 
pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/djando/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 
'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne 
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000041C8160>, 'Connection to 
pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/djando/
```

Comment: It seems to be internet connection problem to me

Comment: No No, I am having a very strong internet connection but it's not working. I just need any other alternative to install Django.

Comment: Check your firewall then? Something is blocking access to the internet for pip.

Answer (score -2):

Create a virtual environment and install django in it. If that doesn't work then try checking your python version and make sure its 3.4+, then upgrade the pip package, it should work after that.

Comment: In what way virtual env could help with `ConnectTimeoutError`?!

Comment: It's a personal suggestion that worked when I had an issue like this, I can't give you a reason why the workaround worked but it did